# Eisenstein's Criterion -- why $p$ has to be prime?

Tags: polynomials

> To prove the validity of the criterion, suppose $Q$ satisfies the criterion for the prime number $p$, but that it is nevertheless reducible in $Q[x]$, from which we wish to obtain a contradiction.
>
> From Gauss' lemma it follows that $Q$ is reducible in $Z[x]$ as well, and in fact can be written as the product $Q = GH$ of two non-constant polynomials $G, H$ (in case $Q$ is not primitive, one applies the lemma to the primitive polynomial Q/c (where the integer c is the content of $Q$) to obtain a decomposition for it, and multiplies c into one of the factors to obtain a decomposition for $Q$).
>
> Now reduce $Q = GH \mod p$ to obtain a decomposition in $(Z/pZ)[x]$. But by hypothesis this reduction for $Q$ leaves its leading term, of the form $ax^n$ for a non-zero constant a $∈ Z/pZ$, as the only nonzero term.
>
> But then necessarily the reductions modulo $p$ of $G$ and $H$ also make all non-leading terms vanish (and cannot make their leading terms vanish), since no other decompositions of $ax^n$ are possible in $(Z/pZ)[x]$, which is a **unique factorization domain**. In particular the constant terms of $G$ and $H$ vanish in the reduction, so they are divisible by $p$, but then the constant term of $Q$, which is their product, is divisible by $p^2$, contrary to the hypothesis, and one has a contradiction.

My question is - why does $p$ have to be prime? I do not see where in this proof the restriction is used. I suspect that it might be the unique factorization domain part but I don't understand why it would be true -- after all, $ax^n$ can not be expressed as a product of polynomials with nonzero constant terms in any field, correct?

Comment: Reduction mod $p$ does not give a field unless $p$ is a prime.

Comment: Two points: A) What Tobias said. If you did the reduction modulo 6 and got a zero, then you could not rule out the possibility that $G$ has constant term $2$ and $H$ has constant term $3$. B) It would be pointless to attempt such a generalization. If a polynomial would satisfy the Eisenstein criteria for some (squarefree!) number $m$, it would satisfy the criteria already for at least one of the prime factors of $m$. Thus we wouldn't win anything.